# SQL Server throwing errors on Drop

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a database in SQL Server but it keeps throwing errors. Could you look at the script and see if I am messing it up somehow?

```
  drop database if exists cptc;

create database cptc;

use cptc;

drop table if exists staff;

create table staff (
  staffID int not null auto_increment,
  fname varchar(25),
  lname varchar(25),
  title varchar(50),
  phone varchar(10),
  building varchar(10),
  room varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(staffID),
FULLTEXT (fname,lname)  
)ENGINE = MYISAM;

INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','michael','herrera','doctor','2539703420','B14','122');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','holly','herrera','teacher','2534667896','B35','116');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','jesse','kirsch','professor','2534567890','B12','112');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','mark','wahlberg','professor','5552345678','B01','112');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','philip','spears','technician','2065672345','B12','123');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','andrew','jackson','teacher','2061234567','B32','101');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','annie','smith','mechanic','2533345609','B23','102');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','alfred','hills','teacher','2535821513','B14','103');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','bobby','jones','nurse','5559876056','B10','104');
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('','tiffany','jones','janitor','2539981265','B02','108');
```

UPDATE: I think I was having Errors because it is MySQL and NOT SQL. Thanks everyone For Your (Really Quick) Answers!

Comment: This is MySql, not Sql Server.

Comment: That Syntax is from mySQL. You have to use MSSQL create-table Syntax on a sql-server-2008

Comment: Oh! That explains a lot. I didn't write it but I am trying to use it. Thanks!

Comment: What are the errors? It isn't clear if you're having problems because your MySQL script is wrong, or because you're running it against SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

This part is MYSQL not SQL Server  `ENGINE = MYISAM;`

here is what the table would look like in SQL Server (sans the fulltext index, you first need to enable fulltext search in order to create a full text index))

```
create table staff (
  staffID int not null identity,
  fname varchar(25),
  lname varchar(25),
  title varchar(50),
  phone varchar(10),
  building varchar(10),
  room varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY(staffID) 
)
```

The drop and create database will look like this

```
USE [master]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = N'cptc')
DROP DATABASE cptc
GO

CREATE DATABASE [cptc]
```

The drop table will look like this

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'staff') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE staff
GO
```

Finally, you need to ommit the column for the identity while inserting, example

```
INSERT INTO staff VALUES ('michael','herrera','doctor','2539703420','B14','122');
```

If you don't ommit the column, you will get the following error

Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

An explicit value for the identity column in table 'staff' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Answer (score 0):

- auto_increment should be identity(1,1)
- ENGINE = MYISAM; doesnt exist what do you expect with it?
- FULLTEXT (fname, lname) is not correct. What do you want, implement full text serach?

Answer (score 0):

The question was not clear. You were creating a table not database.
It would be helpful if you provide the actual error detail.

BTW, you shouldn't put any value for the autoincrement column which will be assigned by server automatically. I guess this was causing the issue.